# get a chunk of items every n items in list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Say I have the following list:

```
l = [4,3,1,5,3,5,8,11,10,4,12,2,1]
```

What is the most pythonic way to slice `l` in order to get chunks of length `n` leaving `k` items between chunks?

For example, if `n=2` and `k=3` the result should be:

```
[4,3,5,8,12,2]
```

Comment: Do you mean what is the most pythonic way to slice list l, so that it returns a chunk of length k for every n in list l? Can you please elaborate more on how you getting the result?

Comment: I think a chunk of length n,  skipping a chunk of length k from the list, l is what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[e for i in range(0, len(l), n+k) for e in l[i:i+n]]
# [4, 3, 5, 8, 12, 2]
```

A `numpy` solution would be:

```
import numpy as np

idx = (np.arange(0, len(l), n+k)[:,None] + np.arange(n)).ravel()
np.array(l)[idx]
# array([ 4,  3,  5,  8, 12,  2])
```

Comment: I think the use of the generator is probably the best way. Note that, it can be done without using numpy as well.

Comment: A generator is great if it already has a generator, but OP has a list to start with, I'm not if a generator fits here. Also yeah the first list comprehension solution is  done without numpy.

Answer (score 1):

My take would be list comprehensions, even though you need to use two because otherwise it would just produce a list of lists.

```
l = [4,3,1,5,3,5,8,11,10,4,12,2,1]
n = 2
k = 3

chunk_l = [y for x in [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(l), n+k)] for y in x]
print(chunk_l)
#[4, 3, 5, 8, 12, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is

```
l = [4,3,1,5,3,5,8,11,10,4,12]
k,n=3,2
res=[]
while l:
    res+=l[:n]
    l=l[n+k:]
print(res)
```

This can be probably be heavily optimized in way of pythonicizity.

Answer (score 0):

One alternate solution using slicing could be following

```
l = np.array([4,3,1,5,3,5,8,11,10,4,12,2,1])
A = l[:][::5]
B = l[1:][::5] 
final = np.insert(B, np.arange(len(A)), A)
# array([ 4,  3,  5,  8, 12,  2])
```

`l[:][::5]` gives you every 5th element starting from the first element and `l[1:][::5]` gives you every 5th element starting from the second element. You then merge the two together